# Android background color of button change automatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have never seen a bug as weird as that before, I'm linking a viewpager with a tablayout, inside the viewpager there are three fragments.

Two of the fragments (let's say fragment 1 & 3) have a button inside them and their colours are both set to "pink". When I first load the app, it shows fragment 1, the button is pink at that moment, however, whenever I switch to fragment 3, the background color of the button is changed to "white" and other attributes of the button stay the same.

This won't happen if I switch to fragment 2. However, if I switch to fragment 3 once, both fragments 1 & 3's button have white background for the rest of the lifetime.

Can someone tell me what's happening here or what could cause this? I'm not changing the style of the buttons in Java files at all.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpWithViewPager(binding.viewPager);
    // setupWithViewPager is a built-in method for TabLayout, setting up this TabLayout with a ViewPager
    // The TabLayout will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles. By doing that,
    // when the user tabs on the tab, the appropriate fragment will be shown in the ViewPager
    // TabLayout provides a horizontal layout to display tabs.
    // Without this line you can still swipe left/right to see all the pages, just cannot tab on the
    // tab to switch pages
    binding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPager);

    // This method sets the toolbar as the app bar for the activity
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    // change the fab icon when the page is changed
    binding.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            changeFabIcon(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

private void setUpWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    // An inner class defined in MainActivity
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "Chats");
    adapter.addFragment(new StatusFragment(), "Status");
    adapter.addFragment(new CallsFragment(), "Calls");
    // We need 3 fragments
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // getMenuInflater is used to instantiate menu XML files into Menu objects.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_search: Toast.makeText(this, "Action Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); break;
        case R.id.menu_more: Toast.makeText(this, "Action More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void changeFabIcon(final int index) {
    binding.fabAction.hide();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (index) {
                case 0: binding.fabAction.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_chat_24)); break;
                case 1: binding.fabAction.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_camera_alt_24)); break;
                case 2: binding.fabAction.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_24)); break;

            }
            binding.fabAction.show();
        }
    }, 400);
}

private static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:title="PepperChat"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicator="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_action"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

fragment_calls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".menu.CallsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invite your friends"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Name of your contact are using PepperChat.\nUse the bottom below to invite them."/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="Invite a friend"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Chat with your friends who are using PepperChat on iphone,\nAndroid or KaiOS phone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

fragment_chats.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".menu.ChatsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invite your friends"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Name of your contact are using PepperChat.\nUse the bottom below to invite them."/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="Invite a friend"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Chat with your friends who are using PepperChat on iphone,\nAndroid or KaiOS phone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following line in both of the xml files, the button appears normally, not sure why though, can someone explain what happened? (is that something related to the theme I'm using?)

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

and my theme is

```
<style name="Theme.PepperChat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

if I change the parent to Theme.MaterialComponent.Light.NoActionBar, then the app works fine without adding backgroundTint.
Again, would like some explanations on why this happens.